# passing variable names as string

Tags: php, oop, variables, string

I'm trying to perform the same function `dosomething()` to multiple variables `$lastsum $avatar $angels $city $square` in PHP.

```
$lastsum->dosomething();
$avatar->dosomething();
$angels->dosomething();
$city->dosomething();
$square->dosomething();
```

Is there a way to make this code cleaner by listing the names of the variables in a string array and perform the function with a for loop. I'm looking for something like this. Does anyone know the right way to do this in PHP?

```
$all = ['lastsum' , 'avatar', 'angels' , 'city' , 'square'];
foreach (....){
    $(nameofvariable)->dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
$all = array($lastsum , $avatar, $angels, $city, $square);
foreach (....){
    $variable->dosomething();
}
```

To achieve *exactly* what you're looking for, use variable variables

```
$all = array('lastsum' , 'avatar', 'angels' , 'city' , 'square');
foreach ($all as $x) {
    $$x->dosomething();
}
```

Many people consider this to be bad style though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use variables variables, it would be more like this:

```
function dosomething(&$var) {
   $var .= 'bar';
}

$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$vars = array('a', 'b');
foreach ($vars as $var) {
   dosomething($$var); 
}

var_dump($a); // foobar
var_dump($b); // barbar
```

If `$a` is an object, then you can do `$$var->dosomething()`.

EDIT: NOTE: In most cases, if you have to use variables variables, you may want to consider using a proper data structure instead, like an array.

Comment: @Mark: Heh. I have yet to find a use for variables variables. I think is was carried over from the `register_globals` era or something. Because an array provide similar functionality and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution. However, you could make use of [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
$all = array( 'lastsum' , 'avatar', 'angels', 'city', 'square' );

foreach ( $all as $var ) {
    $code = "\$${var}->dosomething();";
    eval($code);
}
```

Otherwise, store the objects in an array:

```
$all = array( $lastsum , $avatar, $angels, $city, $square );

foreach ( $all as $obj ) {
    $obj->dosomething();
}
```

Comment: I must ask - why eval? Why don't you just execute the $code right there?

Comment: netcoder and Zenph: Oh! I was not aware of that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
$all = array('lastsum' , 'avatar', 'angels' , 'city' , 'square');

foreach ($all as $x) {
   $GLOBALS[$x]->dosomething();
}
```

Not sure if you could do method calls from the GLOBALS superglobal, but you could most likely access static properties/functions.